# Convert multi-page PDF to single PNG

Tags: preview, image-processing

I have a multi-page PDF.

I want to make a PNG which is just all of these pages appended. I.e., the bottom of page 1 is attached to the top of page 2, etc.

Preview.app's Export... > PNG option saves it as a ... multi-page PNG? I didn't know those were possible, but Preview opens up this PNG like it has many pages and Safari doesn't seem to be able to display both these "pages" properly.

I just want to convert a PDF into a very tall PNG, which is all of the pages on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app [PDFElement6](https://pdf.wondershare.com/how-to/save-multiple-pdf-pages-as-one-image.html), a free trial version is available that will do what you want. The trail version is limited to only a five page PDF.