# Why doesn't Preview save all pages of a certain PDF as a PNG file?

Tags: pdf, preview, graphics

I am trying to save a 30-page PDF as a PNG file. I do this by going to File >> Export. However, only the first four pages save into the PNG. This is the case regardless of whether or not all thirty pages are highlighted in the thumbnail view. Curiously, exporting another long multi-page PDF file works.

Why might this not work for the original PDF? How to get around it? Unfortunately, I can't share the original PDF since it's a sensitive document.

Comment: Is it possible that you are selecting only the first four thumbnails in View->Thumbnails in Preview instead of all before exporting? To select all of the thumbnails, click on any of the thumbnails and press Command+A. In addition, is it only this file or have you tried exporting other long multi-page PDF files? Finally, what is your macOS? Pls update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank @Alper I tried what you suggested, but unfortunately, that didn't work. Curiously, exporting another long multi-page PDF file works. Why might this not work for the original PDF? And how to get around it?

Comment: From your comment this problem is specific to one (or some) PFDs. Can you post a problem PDF somewhere so that we can investigate a bit more? And do you want a multipage PNG or a long thin PNG as in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335497/convert-multi-page-pdf-to-single-png?

Comment: @Alper I find that selecting thumbnails makes no difference. In my tests, the exported PNG always contains all pages however many or few pages are selected. Suspect it has to be some behaviour difference depending on something in the PDF.

Comment: I don't want to upload the problem PDF since it's a sensitive document, sorry. Would there be any reason that a PDF might have this issue? And any way to override it?

Comment: @user2561523 I am just speculating but it might have something to do with the file's permissions some of which you can see through File->Edit Permissions. Changing of those permissions may require a password if you deem necessary, depending on how the creator of the PDF file has set it up.